# Is it possible to run every day except every second Thursday and Friday?

Tags: azure-devops, cron, azure-pipelines, expression, cron-task

I need to make sure that the pipeline runs every day except every second Thursday and Friday by cron. The cron is located in the azure pipeline. Now I have this:

```
schedules:
- cron: 0 19 * * 1-5
  displayName: evening-deployment
  branches:
    include: 
    - develop
  always: false
```

Comment: I don't think there's a cron expression that will do that. You could write a program which only runs if it's not the second Thursday or Friday, then schedule the cron to run every day.

Comment: @Yar Is there any update about the ticket?  Feel free to let me know if  the answers can give you some help.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly meet your requirements.

The definition of cron in Pipeline cannot automatically judge every second Thursday and Friday.

For  workarounds, You can manually check the days of the month that you don't want the Pipeline to run and hardcode the other days in cron.

For example: you need the pipeline run from 1-7,11-21, 25-30.

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 19 1-7,11-21, 25-30 * 1-5" 
  displayName: schedule
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true
```

In this case, you need to manually change the run date at the beginning of each month according to the current month.

Or you can use multiple crons to define run dates for each month of the year. In this case, you can manually update the corresponding crons every year according to the actual date.

For example:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 1-3,5-7 11 1-5" 
  displayName: schedule
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  always: true

- cron: "0 0 1-3,5-7 12 1-5" 
  displayName: schedule
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
  always: true
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc about [cron definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#cron-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

There is no cron onliner for this.
Alternatively you could add multiple schedules, crons, in the same pipeline.

For more info see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#example-nightly-build-with-different-frequencies-1